# How does git reset complete so quickly?

Tags: git, git-reset

I have a chromium repository which is around 60GB in size(30GB downloaded from GitHub). I made quite some changes to the point I messed it up. Permanently deleted files of around 2GB in size and added almost the same amount of files in the repo from another source. After the build failed multiple times, I did a `git reset` and it took around 15 seconds to bring the repo back to its original form. So how does this work? Does the system keeps track of deleted files locally as my internet connection is really poor and downloading 2GB of data usually takes 1 hour so downloading from the internet is not possible.

Comment: You should take a look at the Pro git book, this chapter might answer some of your questions: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F

Comment: When you clone a Git repository, you have your local machine copy the *entire database of all commits*. (You get your own independent names database; their branch names become your remote-tracking names, and you get your own separate branch names, but the *commits* are duplicated.) So after the clone finishes, you have *everything* locally.

Answer (score 1):

Git is *distributed*, which means that your local clone has all the information already. Unless you run `fetch` or `push` (and a few other less common commands), no internet connection is required. Every commit contains a full snapshot of your project at any given time. Why do you think the clone has 30GB in the first place? :)